# I don't understand what return does in programming?

Tags: java, c++

The question basically says it all. I'm a noob so make it gentle.

Comment: Get yourself a copy of Head First Java (http://www.amazon.com/Head-First-Java-Kathy-Sierra/dp/0596009208/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) ... it's probably the gentlest introduction to Java there is.

Answer (score 7):

For these languages, broadly, `return` ends the current function and returns execution flow to the calling function.  You can optionally pass a value after the `return` statement which is the result of the current function in the context of the calling function.

For example:

```
void CallingFunction() {
    int x = OtherFunction();
}

int OtherFunction() {
    return 3;
}
```

The `return` statement ends `OtherFunction()`, i.e. any other statements after the return would not be executed, and the value of `x` in `CallingFunction()` will be `3`, since that is what `OtherFunction()` returned.

This idea of functions and returning values is a very basic, core concept for this style of programming.  As others have pointed out in the comments, you really should check out a book or find a mentor who can help you get started.

[Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735611319) is a very easy to read, high-level overview of the concepts you'll need.

Answer (score 4):

Think of a function as some unit that does work. You may *call* it (ask it to do its work), and it may require some *function arguments* (values from you that it needs to do its job.) When that work is finished, it might *return* something back to you.

For example, a vending machine. The machine is a function: you give it some money, it returns a soda. To you, you "called" the vending machine with some arguments (money), and it gave you a return value. To the machine, it was a function that was called with some arguments (which is saved in its bank), and then used a *return statement* (the crux of your question) to give the caller (you) your return value.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know what functions are?  It does what it sounds like, it ends a (returns from a) function.  If the function you're in is void, then just saying "return" is enough to "return" from the function.  However, if the function you're in has a return value (like an int), then you need to provide that type of value upon returning.

So for example, if I have a function that looks like this (not actual Java):

```
       int oneGenerator()
       {
           return 1;
       }
```

That means that "oneGenerator" ends upon that return line, and also provides the value 1.  I can use that value from a function that called oneGenerator().  For example, say I had a main function that calls oneGenerator

```
    int main()
    {
        int my_int;
        my_int = oneGenerator();
        print(my_int);
    }
```

then that print line (not actual Java code, just a generality) would output 1.

Answer (score 2):

Return does nothing but place a value on the stack, so that calling function can pick it up after the procedure block execution ends. I recommend reading a book on computer architecture. It's worth understanding those things even if you program in a high level language.

Comment: I'd think it'd be better to get the concept of a function down first before trying to explain how it *may* be implemented on *some* architectures.

Comment: @GMan I think I didn't expect the question to be that high-level. I first thought he understood what 'return's outcome is, but wants to know how it really works.